# Finding the leading element in a matrix that has the smallest column number

Tags: c, pointers, matrix

I need to find the first leading element (the first number in a row that is different from 0) that is in the smallest column.

For example, in the matrix `{(0, 2, 2), (2, 3, 5), (0, 2, 5)}`, the leading element is 2: second row, first column.

In the matrix `{(0, 0, 6), (0, 0, 5), (0, 0, 2)}`, the leading element is 6.

```
bool find_leading_elements(double a[][M], int n, int m, int *row, int *column) {
    int i, j, first_j = 0, count = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            if (a[i][j] != 0)
                first_j = min(first_j, j);
            else 
                count++;
        }
    }

    if (count == n * m)
        return false;
    else {
        *row = i;
        *column = first_j;
        return true;
    }
}
```

I wrote this code which correctly gives me the smallest column, but I'm not sure how to get the right row. Do you have any suggestions?

*Note:* at `min(first_j, j)`, `min` is just a function that gives me the smallest column every time I find a place that doesn't have a zero.

Comment: Welcome to SO! How do you define "smallest column"? Is this the sum of the column, the count of elements in the column or index number of the column (i.e. `j`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line `double a[][M]` should be `int (*a)[3]`

You can check each element from `a[0][0]`, `a[1][0]`, `a[2][0]`, `a[0][1]`, ..... until `a[i][j] != 0` or end

The following `code` could work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool find_leading_elements(int (*a)[3], int n, int m, int* row, int* col) {
  for (int j = 0; j != m; ++j)
    for (int i = 0; i != n; ++i)
      if (a[i][j] != 0) {
        *row = i;
        *col = j;
        return true;
      }
  return false;
}

int main() {
  int a[3][3] = {
    {0, 2, 2},
    {2, 3, 5},
    {0, 2, 5}
  };
  int row;
  int col;
  if (find_leading_elements(a, 3, 3, &row, &col))
    printf("row= %d col = %d \n", row, col);
  else
    printf("No answer\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: why couldn't it be double?!

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Because use `a[i][j] != 0`

Comment: that works almost equally well with double... in any case `int a[][M]` is equivalent to `int (*a)[M]` as a function parameter.

Comment: I think that for double should use like `a[i][j] <= ... && a[i][j] >= ...`